# SimpleDateFormat produce wrong result

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm using a method to map an object to the a model which contains a date. In the eclipse debug I see the correct date but when displayed in postman I get the date minus one.

expected result : 2020-02-28

result :  2020-02-27T23:00:00.000+0000

this is my code:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
dateFormat.setLenient(false);
try {
    seance.setDate(dateFormat.parse("2020-02-28 11:04:05.768"));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What is the default timezone on your system? You're parsing the date and time without an explicit timezone, so it's using the system's default. Most likely at `2020-02-28 11:04:05.768` in your timezone, it's actually 27 February UTC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is timezone.

Default data serialize convert date in UTC, you can see '+0000'

The Date format result is ISO1861 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

You can resolve your problem using custom data serialize or try set you env to expected date
`TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));`